# How do I get the exact Sybase ASE version using JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, sap-ase

It turned out, that the SQL syntax for creating a trigger has changed between ASE 15.7 and 16.0. While in the former

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
```

must be used, the later await

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ...
```

must be used.

I know, on SQL it's `SELECT @@version` or using `sp_version`, but with JDBC?

Comment: `create trigger` (sans the `or replace` clause) still works in ASE 16.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running select@@version through a JDBC connection should work and yield the same information as returned through isql.

[Sample Code](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0707/html/prjdbc0707/prjdbc0707205.htm) from SAP/Sybase documentation.

Comment: Correct, our code was wrong (starting with index=0 to get the strings results);

Comment: `select @@version` worked for me.